# Django REST framework: restricting user access for objects

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a REST API for books:

```
/api/book
/api/book/{book_id}
```

A user should have access to his books only. The way I'm doing this now is by filtering the result using username i.e Book.objects.all().filter(owner=request.user)

views.py

```
class Book_List(APIView):

    permission_classes=(permissions.IsAuthenticated)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        **books= Book.objects.all().filter(owner=request.user)**
        serializer = BookSerializer(books, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = BookSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,   status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)    

#/book/{pk}
class Book_Detail(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated)

    def get_object(self, pk, request):
        try:
            return Book.objects.get(pk=pk, owner=request.user)
        except Playlist.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        book = self.get_object(pk, request)
        serializer = BookSerializer(playlist, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        book= self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = BookSerializer(playlist, data=request.data, context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        book= self.get_object(pk)
        book.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('url', 'owner','title', 'created_date', 'shared_with', 'tracks')       

class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    books = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True,view_name='playlist-detail', read_only=True)
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'owner', 'books')
```

But is this the correct way?

Does Django Rest Framework provide any in-built solution for this?

Does the solution lie in permissions? If yes, then how do we set it for all objects created by a user (I understand the for getting a particular object we can put a permission check like `obj.user==request.user`). Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`ModelViewset`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset), which contains all the logic for the typical CRUD:

```
class BooksViewSet(ModelViewset):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    permission_classes=[permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Books.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.data.owner = self.request.user
        super(BooksViewSet, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. This was helpful. In DRF 3.0.2, the above implementation of get_queryset gave an error but this woked:

def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer to take in account this detail, thanks.

Comment: The perform_create implementation caused the error `AttributeError: 'OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'pk'` in my project (DRF 3.8.2). Replacing the two lines in this method with `serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)` fixed it. (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/2964#issuecomment-105441722)